# Reading large XML file using xmerl crashes the node

Tags: elixir

I have the following code that reads a wikipedia dump file (~50 GB) and delivers pages on request:

```
defmodule Pages do
  def start_link(filename) do
    pid = spawn_link(__MODULE__, :loop, [filename])
    Process.register(pid, :pages)
    pid
  end

  def next(xml_parser) do
    send(xml_parser, {:get_next, self()})
    receive do
      {:next_page, page} -> page
    end
  end

  def loop(filename) do
    :xmerl_sax_parser.file(filename,
      event_fun: &event_fun/3,
      event_state: :top)
    loop_done
  end

  defp loop_done do
    receive do
      {:get_next, from} -> send(from, {:next_page, nil})
    end
    loop_done
  end

  defp event_fun({:startElement, _, 'page', _, _}, _, :top) do
    :page
  end

  defp event_fun({:startElement, _, 'text', _, _}, _, :page) do
    :text
  end

  defp event_fun({:characters, chars}, _, :text) do
    s = List.to_string(chars)
    receive do
      {:get_next, from} -> send(from, {:next_page, s})
    end
    :text
  end

  defp event_fun({:endElement, _, 'text', _}, _, :text) do
    :page
  end

  defp event_fun({:endElement, _, 'page', _}, _, :page) do
    :top
  end

  defp event_fun({:endDocument}, _, state) do
    receive do
      {:get_next, from} -> send(from, {:done})
    end
    state
  end

  defp event_fun(_, _, state) do
    state
  end
end
```

Since the code uses `SAX` parser I would expect constant memory footprint. When I try to read first 2000 pages using

```
Enum.each(1..2000, fn(x) -> Pages.next(Process.whereis(:pages)); end)
```

the `:pages` process uses `1,1 GB` of memory according to `:observer.start()`. When I try to read 10000 pages, the whole thing crashes:

```
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 5668310376 bytes of memory (of type "heap").
```

When I open `erl_crash.dump` using dump viewer I see the following:
[image]

Is something wrong with the code above? Is GC not quick enough? Although I can see the memory per process it doesn't tell me a lot. How can I see where this memory actually goes?

P.S. Here is a link to a crash dump from today: https://ufile.io/becba.
The number of atoms is 14490, the `MsgQ` is 2 for `:pages` and 0 for all other processes.

Comment: What error message do you get when it crashes?

Comment: I added the error message

Comment: Maybe it's filling the atom table? See [this thread](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-March/025592.html) on xmerl. "What I find is a problem is that xmerl **produces new atoms** for every element name or **namespace URI** it parses from the input.".

The answer there suggests using the erlsom sax parser instead of xmerl.

Comment: thanks, I don't think that it's atom table. Atoms are process independent, right? But the dump tells that `:pages` process is to blame, so it's something else.

Comment: Even though the code runs in another _erlang_ process, the atom table global in the running _VM_ process. I'll elaborate more in an answer below.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize it was another node running. But the atom table may still be filling up in the :pages node. It is the one actually running the xmerl parser, right?

Comment: @LauroMoura the Atom table's memory usage is not counted in a process's memory usage for me in either Observer or `erlang:process_info`.

Comment: @damluar can you check how many atoms were used by the VM when it crashed? It should be present in the crash dump, near the top, in a line like `Atoms: 123456`.

Comment: @damluar does the crash viewer not have a "MsgQ" column for you? or did you miss including it in the screenshot? Can you please add that?

Comment: @Dogbert, I updated the question, there are 14490 atoms and MsgQ is 2 for `:pages`. Instead of posting more screenshots I decided to attach crash file.

Comment: @damluar Hey. I would love to investigate this in detail if you've still not solved it. Can you reproduce this with a smaller file? Maybe upto a couple hundred MB? Can you link me to such a file?

Answer (score 2):

The default max number of atoms is slightly over [1 million atoms](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html#atoms). Given the English Wikipedia [has over 5 million articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Statistics) and  [xmerl seems to create an atom for each namespace URI](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2007-March/025592.html), I think it may be the culprit.

Also, trying the code below on Elixir fails with just a "stack smashing error".

```
Enum.each(1..2000000, fn (x) ->
  x
  |> Integer.to_string
  |> String.to_atom
end)
```

But if I raise the atom limit to something like 5 million with the environment variable `ELIXIR_ERL_OPTIONS="+t 5000000"`, the problem vanishes.

Comment: this seems like a massive oversight in xmerl. considering it's like the easiest way to DOS an erlang service, you would think they'd have used binaries or strings.